# Can the app provide Jetpack Compose view for the SDK to recreate?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

We are planning to redesign some layouts in the SDK. Right now we use XML and allow the client's app to override the layouts, by them simply copying our XML files and applying customization, **without modifying the IDs of the elements**. Now, I am not sure how would it be possible to do something similar with Jetpack compose.

I am looking the following approach from our IOS SDK to be implemented in the Android:

1. We create interfaces of our UIViews (Like Language selection View, which has SearchView, two TextViews and a button).
2. Then we expose this interface and create a static method, which accepts concrete implementations of the views.
3. Then our SDK checks if the client app actually did modifications and if he did, we inflate the supplied views.

Would it be possible with Jetpack Compose? I would assume you can also expose interfaces and then client apps provide the layout structure. However, we would **not like** to let the client app **to handle the state**. We would like for them to use Jetpack compose **only** for the layout display.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your view lambda arguments with `@Composable`, so those can be used as view builders:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SdkView(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (SomeState) -> Unit,
) {
    // here you can use rememberSaveable or view model instead to get more reliable state storage 
    val state = remember { SomeState() }
    Column {
        title()
        content(state)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ClientView(
) {
    SdkView(
        title = {
            Text("Hello")
        },
        content = { state ->
            // build view depending on state
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, definitely promising! However, we should then expose our SDK's view state to the client view? Suppose we have loading, success, and error states. Should we expose them? What if we would like to navigate a user after success state? We would like to handle all that internally and only expose SdkView for the stateless UI stuff

Comment: Also how should handle the state? Should I expose the state, and then the clients view would render the view depending on the state? I personally would like for the to state be internal and only accept the views. Would it work if I would expose 3 methods, each of them accepts UI elements for loading, success and failure views? Then I would get the views and render them internally.

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov sure, you don't have to give the actual state to the user. Your `SdkView` can have only stateless arguments like `title`, and depending on your state you can choose which view to use for drawing, using `if`, `when`, etc.